# Dynamic Programming: max sum through a a 2 column list, left column skips a row

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic, dynamic-programming

To preface, my English is not quite perfect so apologies for any mistakes.

The problem goes as follows:

Given a list of two choices in each column, determine the maximum sum possible from choosing only one of the two options in the column. The twist is: if the bottom of the two values is chosen, the next column is entirely skipped.

Example:

```
5
9 3 5 7 3
5 8 1 4 5
```

If you were to choose 5 initially from [9, 5], the column [3, 8] would be skipped. Whereas, if 9 was chosen, the next column would NOT be skipped and you could choose from [3, 8] (if 8 was chosen, the next column would be skipped and if 3 was chosen, it would not be, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Let N be the number of columns, then we can store our choices in an array a(2 X N).
And lets define a function f(i,j) which gives the maximum possible sum from the first j+1 columns(0,1...j) where in j-th column we either pick the first option(i=0) or we pick the second option(i=1).
So the answer to this problem will be max(f(i,j)) for each i=[0,1] and j=[0,1,...N-1].
For each column j we need to handle 2 cases:
1- choosing the first option ---> f(0,j)
2- choosing the second option ---> f(1,j)

To calculate the values of column j ( f(0,j) , f(1,j) ) we need to consider these cases for column j-1:
1- we picked the first option from column j-1
2- we did not pick any option from column j-1(means we picked the second option from column j-2)
note: we can not pick the second option from column j-1 because we are picking an option from column j according to our function definition.
Here is the code written in C++

```cpp
    int OO = 1e6;// a big value
    
    //reading the input
    int a[2][100];
    int N;  cin >> N;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) cin >> a[0][i];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) cin >> a[1][i];

    //initialization
    int f[2][100];
    f[0][0] = a[0][0];
    f[1][0] = a[1][0];

    int result = max(f[0][0],f[1][0]);

    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        int val1 = f[0][i - 1];
        int val2 = -OO;
        if (i - 2 >= 0)
            val2 = f[1][i - 2];
        f[0][i] = max(val1, val2) + a[0][i];
        f[1][i] = max(val1,val2) + a[1][i];
        result = max(result, max(f[0][i], f[1][i]));
    }
    cout << result << endl;
```

Comment: your feedback is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

When you attempt to solve this using DP, the most important aspect of the problem is to define the right states of the DP.

Define `D[i][j] = maximum sum until index i, if u choose element j` || `j in [0,1]`

```
L = [
[9, 3, 5, 7, 3],
[5, 8, 1, 4, 5]
]

def find_max_sum(L):
    D = [[0, 0] for _ in range(len(L[0]))]

    D[0][0] = max(L[0][0], 0)
    D[0][1] = max(L[1][0], 0)

    for i in range(1, len(D)):
        D[i][0] = L[0][i] + max(D[i-1])
        if i > 1:
            D[i][1] = max(L[1][i] + max(D[i-2]), max(D[i-1]))
        else:
            D[i][1] = max(L[1][i], max(D[i-1]))

    return max(D[-1])

print(find_max_sum(L))
```